# Map projection from epsg:4326 to epsg=3857 and Bering strait problem

Tags: bokeh, geospatial, geopandas, map-projections

I am using python bokeh to project data over a world map.
I have a geopandas geopdwd init with crs="epsg:4326" and I want to project it to a mercator  world map using [bokeh tile](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/geo.html). Then I fill countries have selected by some color.

Basicaly I need to convert my geopandas geometry (an epsg:4326) to epsg=3857 one.
For this purpose I do:

```
geopdwd = geopdwd.to_crs(epsg=3857)
```

But as you can see I have a problem with the russian part and specially with the Bering strait. It is colorized in the wrong part ...
I thing I need to force it to the right part of my world map.
Do have any idea to deal with that problem ? Do I need to use an other projection ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For interested people I have solved the problem, have a look to my Bokeh thread : https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/bokeh-tile-antimeridian-problem/6978